# How do you set the Accessibility setting description for your app when creating a AccessibilityEventService?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

[image]I have a working AccessibilityEventService running for my app.  How do you set the description in the general Settings menu under Accessibility, for my package, i.e., com.my.package?

All I get is the default 'No description provided.'

I've looked in onServiceConnected().  I'm not currently using any type of manifest XML definition for the serivce, just the AccessibilityEventService.

Comment: What do you mean by description?  You mean the string that shows up in the list of available services, where you'd go to enable it?

Comment: You go to Settings system app and then to Accessibility,  you then get a list of services, when you click on one of the Services to turn it 'on' or 'off', the default description is 'No Description provided.'  The provided image is when I clicked on the ClockBack service.  I'd like to include a better message than 'No Description provided.'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the relevant items to make this happen.  Here are the two relevant files, and important pieces of information.  Scaffolding and such removed.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    <service>
        <meta-data
            android:resource="@xml/service_config" />
    </service>
</application>
```

service_config.xml

```
<accessibility-service 
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    />
```

Comment: Not for the description. Your code doesn't get executed when the services menu gets created. Many other aspects of the meta-data can be set in code, but not this.